# PDFを指定したページごとに分割し、それぞれ指定した名前を付けて保存したい

Tags: python, pdf

PDFは全62ページとしました。
このPDFに対して下記のような辞書を作成しました。中身は保存する名前とそのページ数です。

```
pdf_dic = {
    'tokyocaffe':3,
    'yokohamabook':10,
    'saitamahouse':5,
    'tokyoshrine':19,
    'aichicoffee':7,
    'fukuokafood':9,
    'tokyobook':3,
    'kyotocaffe':2,
    'shigafood':3,
    'tokyogoods':1
}
```

1-3ページはtokyocaffe.pdf、4-13ページはyokohamabook.pdfといったように順番にPDFを作成したいです。

PyPDF2を使用して１ページずつ分割することはできるのですが、辞書の内容を絡めて処理する方法がわからないです。
わかる方いましたらご教授願います。

Comment: 今はどんなコードなんでしょうか？

Comment: この記事とかが参考になるのでは？ [Extract specific pages of PDF and save it with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51567750/9014308)

Comment: ちなみに提示された辞書の例と、作成したいとされるファイル名・ページ範囲の記述が微妙にズレている感じですが、どちらが正しいのかあるいは辞書から何か変換や処理を行ってファイル名・ページ範囲が出来るのでしょうか？

Comment: 遅くなり申し訳ございません。辞書から何か変換するという処理はないです。ご対応ありがとうございました、先にいただいた回答で解決しました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PyPDF2.PdfMerger.append`](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfMerger.html#pypdf.PdfMerger.append)の`pages`引数に(`開始位置`, `終了位置+1`)のタプルを指定することで複数ページの分割ができます。(開始位置と終了位置は0始まりです)
その仕組みと辞書型を組み合わせることで目的のコードを作成できます。

**サンプルコード**
※単一のコードで完結して動作するよう、デジ庁のオープンデータのガイドライン(全7ページ)を[ダウンロード](https://www.digital.go.jp/assets/contents/node/basic_page/field_ref_resources/f7fde41d-ffca-4b2a-9b25-94b8a701a037/7c57e1a9/20220523_resources_data_guideline_01.pdf)します。(要`pip install requests`)

```
import pathlib

# ファイルがない場合はオープンデータのガイドラインをダウンロードする
file_name = "20220523_resources_data_guideline_01.pdf" 
if not pathlib.Path(file_name).exists():
    import requests # 要 pip install requests
    url = "https://www.digital.go.jp/assets/contents/node/basic_page/field_ref_resources/f7fde41d-ffca-4b2a-9b25-94b8a701a037/7c57e1a9/20220523_resources_data_guideline_01.pdf" 
    res = requests.get(url)
    with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
        f.write(res.content)

import PyPDF2

pdf_dic = {
    'hoge':3,
    'fuga':2,
    'piyo':2,
}

start = 0 # 開始位置
for key in pdf_dic:
    merger = PyPDF2.PdfMerger()
    end = start + pdf_dic[key] # 終了位置+1
    merger.append(file_name, pages=(start, end)) # 複数ページを抽出
    merger.write(f"{key}.pdf") # 保存
    start = end
```